# Backbone: before route

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

There are lot of topics in google, but any full and working  example.

***How can I wrap router's navigation in such way that I can check conditions and cancel navigation if needed?***

P.S. I see ideas with _.wrap, overriding Backbone.Router.prototype.route etc, but there are not complete example.
Also I saw [backbone-route-filter](https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter) but have no ideas how integrate it in my application.

Comment: Those configured routes will trigger some js code, then you can execute any js validation and use the window.location.replace() to redirect the site to another url. This works for you?

Comment: redirecting has a catch, if you are redirecting to a url, which in turn results in return will get into deadlock. be careful about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that I extended Backbone.Router. I wish my router helps you. 
I added a property toEvaluate with the preconditions by route and I added evaluateRoutesFn with the function that will evaluate them before to navigate some route.

An example of my route could be:

```
var MySubRouter = Backbone.ModuleRoute.extend({
      //hasPermissions is static
      //if you want a function of an instance you can use a function instead

      evaluateRoutesFn: SomeView.hasPermissions,

      toEvaluate: {
          routeA: {
              modulePreconditions: [SomeView.CONDITION_A, ...]
          }
      },

      routeA: function(param1, param2) {
          //the route to navigate with preconditions
      },
```

The method with the permissions return true or false or an error.

```
var MyView = ModuleView.extend({}, {
    CONDITION_A: "conditionA",
    hasPermissions: function (condition, properties) {
          switch (condition) {
              case MyView.CONDITION_A:
                  return app.ConditionA;
              default:
                  return true;
          }
    }
});
```

And the more important is ModuleRoute. Here you have the base of my moduleRoute. I added more things. Like error control. I saved all the current routes in each module of my app... And more. You can add whatever you need. It is really useful.

```
  Backbone.ModuleRoute = Backbone.Router.extend({
      evaluateRoutesFn: null,
      toEvaluate: null,

      constructor: function (prefix, options) {
          this._finalRoutes = {};
          Backbone.SubRoute.prototype.constructor.call(this, prefix, options);
      },

      onRoutes: function (route) {
          var aps = Array.prototype.slice;
          var args = aps.call(arguments);
          args.shift();
          var routeName = this.routes[route];

          var evalResult = true;
          try {
              var toEval = this.toEvaluate && this.toEvaluate[routeName];
              if (toEval) {
                  evalResult = this.evalPreconditions(toEval.modulePreconditions, args);
                  //more future preconditions
              }
          }
          catch (err) {
              evalResult = false;
          }

          if (evalResult)
              try {
                  this._finalRoutes[route].apply(this, args);
              }
              catch (err) {
                  window.history.back(); //go back, error control...
              }
          else
              window.history.back(); //no permissions, go back
      },

      evalPreconditions: function (preconds, args) {
          if (!this.evaluateRoutesFn) {
              throw "WARNING: Evaluate routes function must be overriden to evaluate them. " +
                    "Don't assign toEvaluate if you won't do it. The evaluation has been skipped.";
          }
          if (!preconds)
              return true;

          var evalResult = true;
          for (var i = 0, len = preconds.length; i < len; i++) {
              evalResult = this.evaluateRoutesFn(preconds[i], args);
              if (!evalResult) {
                  throw "ERROR: The precondition is not truth.";
                  break;
              }
          }
          return evalResult;
      },

      route: function (route, name, callback) {
          this._finalRoutes[route] = (!callback) ? this[name] : callback;
          var that = this;
          callback = function (path) {
              return function () {
                  var aps = Array.prototype.slice;
                  var args = aps.call(arguments);
                  args.unshift(path);
                  that.onRoutes.apply(that, args);
              };
          } (route);
          return Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(this, route, name, callback);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try overriding Backbone.history.route:

```
var bbhRoute = Backbone.history.route;
Backbone.history.route = function(route, callback) {
  return bbhRoute.call(Backbone.history, route, function(fragment) {
    // if (decide if you want to prevent navigation) {
    //    window.history.back(); // to ensure hash doesn't change
    //    return;
    // }

    // if you want to let it happen:
    return callback.apply(this, arguments);
  });
};
```

Comment: in router initialize method

Comment: better put it outside the router